# What is Hitsugi's age?

Tags: riddle-story-of-devil

Hitsugi and Chitaru are yuri characters. Chitaru's age seems according, but what about Hitsugi? She is really smaller than Chitaru.

[image: hitsugi and chitaru]

Comment: and here i thought the only canon shoujo ai/yuri i would expect from this series was from the main 2 characters. akuma no riddle has just jumped up a couple of spots on my list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hitsugi](http://akuma-no-riddle.wikia.com/wiki/Hitsugi_Kirigaya) and [Chitaru](http://akuma-no-riddle.wikia.com/wiki/Chitaru_Namatame) are both at the *same age*, which is 15 years old. It is true that Hitsugi actually looks like a little girl, her height is also not up to her age, not even close, so it seems like Hitsugi is younger than Chitaru, but it's not.

[image]

Hitsugi doesn't even seem to have matured yet, which is the actual reason.

Answer (score 1):

According to *Akuma no Riddle AK*, a social game which was released in 2012 (before the anime in 2014), Hitsugi and Chitaru were both 15 years old, even though Hitsugi was often to be mistaken as primary school student due to her short height.

[image: Hitsugi Kirigaya's profile] [image: Chitaru Namatame's profile]

<sup>Image courtesy of [naomamayu's blog (Japanese)](http://naomamayu.blog.jp/archives/cat_344404.html)</sup>

<sup>*The game was shut down in 2015</sup>

Comment: To be fair, the Wikia used the same link as the reference, but didn't mention it explicitly. It was only mentioned on the revision history.